# Getting Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'. programmatically click input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
function Dropzone(props: propType) {
    const fileInputRef = useRef(null);

    function handleClick(){
        fileInputRef.current?.click()
    }

    return (
        <p onClick={()=>handleClick()} className='mt-2 cursor-pointer text-sky-800'>Browse on your computer</p>
        <input type="file" className='hidden' ref={fileInputRef}></input>
    )
}
```

I'm trying to achieve when clicking on

```html
<p>
```

through

```js
const fileInputRef = useRef(null)
```

I can programatically click on

```html
<input type='file'> </input>
```

Getting Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: `useRef<HtmlInputElement>(null)`?

Comment: Please adjust the title of your question to clarify that you're not asking how to click the element (which you already know, and which works?) but rather how to solve the type error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that here typescript unable to infer the correct type of `fileInputRef`. This can be easily solved by explicitly passing the type parameter to the generic `useRef` hook:

```
import { useRef, RefObject } from 'react';

function Dropzone(props: propType) {
  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  function handleClick() {
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.click();
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p onClick={handleClick} className='mt-4 cursor-pointer text-blue-600'>
        Browse the file
      </p>
      <input type="file" className='hidden' ref={fileInputRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```